# Isotope sort randomly

Tags: jquery-isotope

I have an issue sorting items (Wordpress single posts) with isotope. I would like to sort randomly (without having to click on a selector). Here is my jQuery code :

```
var $container = $('#isotope-list');
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector : '.item', 
        layoutMode : 'masonry',
        getSortData: {
            name: '.cima-title'
        },
        sortBy: 'random'
    });
```

Items are still sorting by last published.

Anyone can help? Thank you

Comment: "doesn't work" like your computer catches fire?  You should be very specific about the details when you observe that something "doesn't work".

Comment: I am not a native English speaker so sorry if you might not understand. I was meaning that isotope items are not appearing randomly.